# Property Binding as function parameter in Html template of Angular 7

Tags: angular, property-binding

I have an issue in html template. I want to call a function and pass a param to function. This param is a property in component class. How could I bind this property in function call.
I have tried different options but could not get success.

1.

```
<input type="button" class='Button' value='Back' 
(click)="showGrid('{{"./app/setup/" + url}}')" />
```

2.

```
<input type="button" class='Button' value='Back' 
(click)="showGrid('./app/setup/ + {{url}}')" />
```

3. Using Getter in component.

   get myUrl = function(){
   return "./app/setup/" + ${this.Url}
   }

In html,

```
<input type="button" class='Button' value='Back' 
(click)="showGrid('{{myUrl}}')" />
```

How could I bind the property in function call. Please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: why you are using `{{}}`?

Comment: If I remove it, it is taken as string in param.

Comment: in which format you want your param?

Comment: No specific format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always a good idea to have these literals as `const`. Never hardcode these values in view (html).

Use below approach.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    appUrls = APP_URLS;

    constructor() { }

    showGrid(url) {
        // to-do
    }
}

export const APP_URLS = {
    'BASEURL': '/something',
    'URL1': `./app/setup/${this.BASEURL}`,
};
```

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="button" class='Button' value='Back' (click)="showGrid(appUrls.URL1)" />
```

Comment: In this case,  `./app/setup/${this.BASEURL}` 

${this.BASEURL} is not being resolved and due to this router path not resolved issue occured.

Comment: Put `APP_URLS` in some other file not in the component that gets resolved dynamically.

Comment: I am using a separate file for APP_URLS.
    export const AppLinks = {
    BASE_API_URL : 'http://localhost:8080',
    BASE_APP_URL : './api',
    MENU_URL: '/main/menu',
    SETUP_BASE :  '${BASE_APP_URL}/setup',
    OPERATION_BASE :  '${this.BASE_APP_URL}/operation',
    }

Comment: '${BASE_APP_URL}/Setup' is being used as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
<input type="button" class='Button' value='Back' 
(click)="showGrid('./app/setup/' + url)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="button" class='Button' value='Back' 
(click)="showGrid('./app/setup/' + url)" />
```

Or you can append ./app/setup/ in showGrid function as follows

**HTML code**

```
<input type="button" class='Button' value='Back' (click)="showGrid(url)" />
```

**TS Code**

```
showGrid(urlData){
  urlData = './app/setup/' + urlData;
}
```